# CW complex with fundamental group $\Bbb Z/n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, cw-complexes

I'm just learning about CW complexes. I came across [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1074721/463195%20/): "One way of constructing a connected $2$-dimensional CW complex with fundamental group $\Bbb Z/n$ (for some integer $n\geq 2)$ is to start with the circle $S^1$, and to attach a $2$-cell $D^2$ with the attaching map $\partial D^2\to S^1, z\mapsto z^n$."

When I imagine a circle and a disc attached to it by wrapping it 2 times around, I have two discs attached together so I'd imagine it'd be homeomorphic to a sphere. But according to the answer I quoted I should get fundamental group $\Bbb Z/2$. What am I missing?

Comment: do you know anything about cellular homology so far?

Comment: @Simonsays not yet. Just fundamental groups so far.

Comment: You only have one disc. You started with a circle, and attached one disc.

Comment: @Tyrone I'm confused..I attached one disc but I wrapped it around twice so how come that's not like two discs?

Comment: You only wrapped its boundary sphere $S^1\cong \partial D^2\subseteq D^2$ around a second copy of $S^1$ twice. What's left is a twisted disc, but at no point have you added a second disc.

Comment: @Tyrone sorry for the stupid question.. I still don't see it. Since I glued the boundary of the disc wrapped twice to $S^1$, haven't I thus glued its two halves and created a sphere? I guess my problem is I can't see what this thing looks like. Not sure what you mean by a twisted disc. Isn't it glued to itself? Maybe it will help me more to ask for an example of a non-contractible loop in this space?

Comment: Take a piece of paper, and wrap its edges around themselves twice. How many pieces of paper do you now have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X=S^1 \cup_{z \sim z^n} D^2$ be the $2$-dim CW complex: Our space looks like the upper hemisphere with the equator wrapped $n$ times around itself. 
 Mapping a homotopy class of loops $[\omega]: I \rightarrow X$, we can just count how often they are wrapped around the equator $S^1$. This path can be wrapped once, twice etc. according to the winding number of the map $\partial D \rightarrow S^1 $ and clearly wrapping it $n$ times creates the actual boundary of $X$ (the $n$ wrap), which we can contract to e.g. the North Pole $N$. 
 Therefore we get $n[w]= const_N$ which is the neutral element of $\pi_1$, so $\pi_1(X)\cong \mathbb{Z}_n$. 
 For $n=2$ you get in fact the real projective space $\mathbb{RP}^2$, which is constructed via the quotient space of group-action of the antipodal map on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$. You might also look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_space).

Comment: I'm taking a rubber sheet, and I wrap it around a plate twice. I now get something which (if I pull one of the sheets formed upwards) looks like a sphere. You say it looks like the upper hemisphere with the equator wrapped 2 times around itself, which I don't actually understand..

Comment: you need to be careful with the quotient: you only identify the boundary of the disc with points on S1, the interior remains unchanged. the 2-wrap means that if you go once around the equator, you hit each point twice, since z and z^2 are identified under the quotient .

Comment: I think I get it now. Just to make sure, so this thing doesn't actually exist in $\Bbb R^3$ right?

Comment: @Dan, yes thats how you picture it. I also added an extra paragraph that might be useful to you

Comment: I kept missing that thinking of it the way I did I was actually also gluing the interior, and thinking it embeds in $\Bbb R^3$ also didn't help. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Dan no worries, I know the struggles in Algebraic Topology myself ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can think of that space as $\mathbb{D}^2/\sim$ where $\mathbb{D}^2$ is the closed disk and
$$ (\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))\sim (\cos(\theta+\frac{2\pi}{n}), \sin(\theta+\frac{2\pi}{n}))$$
for all $\theta\in [0,2\pi].$ Using Seifert-van Kampen theorem one can show that its fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}_n.$